# Error in SQLite when a extra condition is added in query to fetch database into cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to display contents of a SQLite database in android. The code works when I don't add any condition on db2.select. However, it flags an error "close was never called on database" when I add a condition to the query.

What is the solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
public class LogDisp extends Activity {
final ResultLog resultlog = new ResultLog(this);
String[] FROM = {_ID,Type,Date,Question,Percent,Avg };
String testtype="Verbal:: Sentence Correction" ;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //String sqlstr="SELECT Date, Question, Avg, Percent FROM TABLE_NAME2 where Question>5";
    String Orderby= Question+"DESC";

    SQLiteDatabase db2 = resultlog.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db2.query(TABLE_NAME2,FROM,null, null, null, null, Orderby);    

    //Cursor cursor =db2.rawQuery(sqlstr, null); 

    ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout ll= new LinearLayout(this);
    sv.addView(ll);

    final TableLayout tv = new TableLayout(this);
    ll.addView(tv);
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        String type=cursor.getString(1) ;
        String date=cursor.getString(2);
        String question=cursor.getString(3);
        String percent=cursor.getString(4);
        String avg=cursor.getString(5);


        TableRow tr= new TableRow(this);
        tv.addView(tr);
        final String space=""+""+""+""+""+"";
        TextView txtview= new TextView(this);
        txtview.setText(date+space+question+space+percent+space+avg);
        tr.addView(txtview); 
    }

     this.setContentView(sv);
     db2.close();
     cursor.close();

}
```

}

And here's my SQLite helper class:

```
public class ResultLog extends SQLiteOpenHelper{ 
 private static final String DATABASE_NAME2 = "LogofResult.db";
 private static final int DATABASE_VERSION2 = 1;

 public ResultLog(Context ctx) { 
        super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME2, null, DATABASE_VERSION2);
     }  

 // Database creation sql statement
    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
                    + TABLE_NAME2+ "(" + 
                    _ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + 
                    Type +" text not null,"+
                    Date     + " integer not null,"+
                    Question + " integer not null,"+  
                    Avg+" real not null,"+
                    Percent +" real not null);" ;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
                database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME2);
                onCreate(db);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> close was never called on database

If it's called, you need to close your database. You can do it in `onDestroy()` method or `onStop()` method.

And `String Orderby= Question+"DESC"` this looks like incorrect, add space here

`Question+" DESC"` and then it should works. This caused your error.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in your Orderby variable. You haven't left a space between the column name and `DESC`

EDIT: Post your logcat here for further assistance

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a space.

```
String Orderby= Question+"DESC";
```

That will produce:

```
questionDESC
```

It needs to be

```
String Orderby= Question+" DESC";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you're trying to close the database while you still have an open cursor. Change the last three lines of your oncreate method to and i think your problem is fixed.

Remember to always close the last thing you opened first.

```
cursor.close();
db2.close();
this.setContentView(sv);
```

Edit: upon further looking i think the fault might also be your missing space between question and desc, but what i described before is something which can give you a lot of trouble when you're inconsistent with the way you close it.